# Error while opening file in python

Tags: python, file-io

```
**w = open("C:\Users\kp\Desktop\example.csv", "w+")**
```

The above code shows the following error

```
**> w = open("C:\Users\kp\Desktop\example.csv", "w+")
            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What can be the actual reasons and possible solutions to this problem?
Note that I'm using PyCharm to work with python, and working with '.csv' files.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes by putting double backslashes. `C:\ ` becomes `C:\\ ` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes (`\`):

```
w = open("C:\\Users\\kp\\Desktop\\example.csv", "w+")
```

or use raw string literals:

```
w = open(r"C:\Users\kp\Desktop\example.csv", "w+")
```

to mean backslash literally.

---

Otherwise, backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

```
>>> print('hello\nworld')  # \n -> newline
hello
world
>>> print('hello\\nworld')
hello\nworld
>>> print(r'hello\nworld')
hello\nworld

>>> print('\U00000064')
d
>>> print('\\U00000064')
\U00000064
>>> print(r'\U00000064')
\U00000064
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! @falsetru

Answer (score -1):

Apart from above answers, In general, if you wish to avoid such errors while giving a path.
I would recommend using:

```
os.path.join()
```

This helps to such Unicode errors in paths and the same line of code works on different OS as Windows and Unix have different path conventions.